# Can't append python prints to a file if the .py program is running in the background

Tags: python-3

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero WH.  I wrote a python program

```
import time
while True:
  print("test")
  time.sleep(2)
```

At the system prompt,

```
/usr/bin/python3 test.py
```

prints fine to the screen.

```
/usr/bin/python3 test.py > x.txt
```

writes the prints to the file just fine.

But

```
/usr/bin/python3 test.py > x.txt &
```

never writes a thing to x.txt.   How can I redirect the output of a background task (ultimately a task launched from crontab) to write out a log file?

Comment: Looks at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function

Comment: The link @Dougie gives is certainly an extensive explanation. Thanks.  Without knowing that buffering takes place and there is a flush() function to deal with it, the thread didn't come up in my searches.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does write to the log file.

The problem is the data is buffered internally until the buffer is full.  The buffer is likely to be 4096 bytes in size.  The "test" text is five bytes (including the line feed).  So the buffer needs 4096/5 writes before the file is written.  That will be 4096/5*2 seconds (over 27 minutes).

I suggest you flush the data if you want it to appear in the file sooner.

Comment: Thanks.  I researched flush and was able to get things working with a strategically placed     sys.stdout.flush() in the real program I'm writing.